# localstorage undefined on ie11 (windows 10) what is the solution?

Tags: ie11-developer-tools

I want to store data in my application in local and i use localstorage. In chrome, firefox, safari it works well but on ie11 window.localstorage undefined. I use HTML5 and the options internet are ok. Is it possible to use localstorage with ie ? If not how to store data in local ? I used amplify.js but the data are not saved when i put off the application. i am on **Windows 10**

Thanks

Comment: To begin with, JavaScript is case-sensitive. `localstorage` is not the same as `localStorage`.

Comment: Thank you but i use the right syntax : localStorage.setItem